# Firebase connection issues

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

The code below crashes my app before it gets a chance to run:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txtname,txtage,txtphone,txtheight;
    Button btnsave;
    DatabaseReference reff;
    Schedule schedule;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        txtname=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtname);
        txtage=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtage);
        txtphone=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtphone);
        txtheight=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtheight);
        btnsave=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnsave);
        schedule=new Schedule();
        reff=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Schedule");
        btnsave.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                int agea=Integer.parseInt(txtage.getText().toString().trim());
                Float hit=         
                Float.parseFloat(txtheight.getText().toString().trim());
                Long phn=Long.parseLong(txtphone.getText().toString().trim());

                schedule.setName(txtname.getText().toString().trim());
                schedule.setAge(agea);
                schedule.setHt(hit);
                schedule.setPh(phn);
                reff.child("schedule1").setValue(schedule);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Data inserted successfully", 
                Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });



        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Firebase connection Success", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
      }
}
```

I am new to Firebase and not sure where I am going wrong, the code runs when my `reff = firebase` line is commented out so there must be a problem with the way I am referencing, but obviously, the code does nothing without the connection to the database, if anyone could help.

Logs from crash as requested:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.notihng/com.example.notihng.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.notihng. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first. 

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2946) 

at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3081) 

at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78) 

at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108) 

at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68) 

at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1831) 

at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 

at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:201) 

at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6806) 

at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 

at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:547) 

at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:873) 

Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Default FirebaseApp is not initialized in this process com.example.notihng. Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first. 

at com.google.firebase.FirebaseApp.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-common@@16.0.4:240) 

at com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase.getInstance(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.6:67) 

at com.example.notihng.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:28) 

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7210) 

at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7201) 

at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1272) 

at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2926) 

... 11 more
```

App Gradle File:

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

 android {
     compileSdkVersion 28
     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.example.notihng"
         minSdkVersion 21
         targetSdkVersion 28
         versionCode 1
         versionName "1.0"
         testInstrumentationRunner 
 "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
     }
     buildTypes {
         release {
             minifyEnabled false
             proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android- 
optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
         }
     }
 }

 dependencies {
     implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
     implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
     implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint- 
      layout:1.1.3'
     implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.6'
     testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
     androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
     androidTestImplementation 
     'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso- 
      core:3.0.2'
    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you provide the stacktrace for your crash using logcat?

Comment: This is what i got in the crash report:

Comment: Did you add the google-services.json and change the gradle files?

Comment: I highly recommend searching for the error message you get: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Default+FirebaseApp+is+not+initialized+in+this+process

Comment: Yes i added the google-servies.json and changes the gradle files

Comment: Got it working guys,cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it working guys thanks for all the help.
It was the dependencies in project gradle, when i changed them to 
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1'
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
It promted me to install new sdk files.
Not sure if the default dependencies just werent working or the downloading files was  the fix, but its working now anyways, thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

The crash report clearly says the problem in your code.

> Make sure to call FirebaseApp.initializeApp(Context) first

You need to initialize it first before using it like the following.

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);
```

In your `build.gradle` file, there are two declarations of adding the following plugin.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I would like to suggest you remove the first one. Keep the one at the end of your gradle file.

Comment: Hi, I've tried placing this under
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);  But its still gives me the same error as before and crashes.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Can you please take a look? Let me know if that solves your problem.

Comment: Got it working @Reaz, was the build gradle default dependencies werent correct and i replaced them with  'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.1' classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0' . Thanks for the help.

Comment: Good to know that you could solve the problem. Please accept the answer if helpful.